# PHP: How to make session cookies kept until browser cloeses?

Tags: php, session

I'd like to set the PHP session lifetime as long as possible util the browser is closed. Is it possible to implement this just by settings something in PHP script? Or do I have to change anything in PHP.ini configuration file?

Answer (score 2):

PHP's default session setting is to make the session cookies... session cookies. They'll last for the lifetime of the browser and get deleted when it's closed/quit/exited. The relevant .ini setting is [`session.cookie_lifetime`](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-lifetime)

Answer (score 1):

I just went through this myself recently.

Here is the website I used:

http://www.captain.at/howto-php-sessions.php

Pay attention to the "session.php" section at the bottom.

Comment: @MrCarney: The correct answer is given below (by Marc B). Unless something was changed in PHP configuration, you don't have to do anything to achieve, what is asked about. By default all cookies are kept only until browser exits. You have to take extra work (i.e. set their lifetime), if you want them to be kept longer.

Answer (score 0):

before any output;

```
<?
session_set_cookie_params(0);

session_start();

/* Set to 0 if you want the session
   cookie to be set until the user closes
   the browser. Use time() + seconds
   otherwise. */
?>
```

Comment: The correct answer is given above (by Marc B). Unless something was changed in PHP configuration, you don't have to do anything to achieve, what is asked about. By default all cookies are kept only until browser exits. You have to take extra work (i.e. set their lifetime), if you want them to be kept longer.